# android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION not woking in Android Q Beta 5(QPP5)

Tags: android, android-location, android-10.0

1) Requested both background and forground location.

```
String [] permission = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        requestPermissions(permission,100);
```

2)Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

3) On release build onRequestPermissionsResult shows not granted when "Allow all the time" is selected with below error.

```
2019-07-31 16:15:27.329 1293-1311/? E/PackageManager: Cannot grant restricted non-exempt permission android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION for package xyz.abc.com

2019-07-31 16:49:38.412 11858-11858/? D/MainActivity: permission: android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION 
2019-07-31 16:49:38.412 11858-11858/? D/MainActivity: permission: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
2019-07-31 16:49:38.412 11858-11858/? D/MainActivity: grantResults: -1
2019-07-31 16:49:38.412 11858-11858/? D/MainActivity: grantResults: 0
```

**Note:** 
Device: Pixel 3a XL

Works well with debug build but fails in release build.

Device: Pixel 3 XL.
Works well with both debug and release builds.

Comment: Have you added permission in `menifest` file, if not then add below permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Comment: Added check Note. Only Pixel 3a Xl has issue.

Comment: [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137781887) seems related. Google claims it will have been fixed in the next beta.

Comment: Ah thanks missed to check the "issuetracker.google.com"

Answer (score 0):

AndroidQ Beta 6 solved the issue.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/final-beta-update-official-android-q.html